# Block access to assets folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want the following; Only index.php should have access to all folders in the server, users of the website should not be able to access folders like "assets".

I tried the following codes:

```
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
<FilesMatch index\.php>
        Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

And

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
```

And

```
require local
```

Could anyone help me out? I really need to block access to the "assets" folder and other folders

Comment: have you ensured you [can override](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#AllowOverride) this directive in .htaccess?

Comment: or let's clarify: what is going wrong? do anyone still has access to /assets, no one has access to anything including index.php or index.php cannot ask for /assets through network?

Comment: @skyboyer If I request https://url/assets/ I can access it, and if I request https://url/assets/images/logo.png, I can access it. I want nobody to have access to them but index.php (otherwise I can't use images for example)

Comment: @skyboyer Allow override is on

Comment: ok, how about `deny from all`? if you leave just that is it working as expected?

Comment: I made a .htaccess file, put your first code in it, and it did what you wanted. So something else is the problem. I'd recommend looking in your apache error log.

Comment: @skyboyer If I do deny from all. It blocks everything also index.php, and I want the assets to load in side my index.php. So for example I want logo.png to load in side index.php, but when I request url/assets/images/logo.png I want it to give a 403

Comment: What does "load inside index.php" mean? If you want to be able to use a tag like `<img src='assets/images/logo.png'>` then you have to realise that the browser will request that file, and the restrictions will apply just the same as if it was accessed direct.

Comment: @ChrisLear Yes that is what I mean

Comment: @SanderBakker If you prevent a browser from accessing a file, then it will be inaccessible to the same browser trying to access it as part of rendering an html document. I think what you're trying to do is fundamentally impossible in the way you want to do it